# Why is this list index out of range?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am currently working on a school assignment from the AI department where I have to make a Genetic Algorithm. It is meant to solve the 8 Queens problem using a list called board, where each index is a column and the value in that index is the row. The algorithm itself works fine, but every time I try to run it, it crashes after the while loop reaches populationSize - 2 (in this case 18). The error that I get is about line:

```
child = reproduce(population[l], population[l + 1], nqueens)
```

and the error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "nqueens1.py", line 370, in 
>       main()
>
> File "nqueens1.py", line 363, in main
>       genetic_algorithm(board)
>
> File "nqueens1.py", line 291, in genetic_algorithm
>       child = reproduce(population[l], population[l + 1], nqueens)
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I am trying to understand what is going wrong, but I do not see why it would go out of range. Here is the code that I have so far:

Function Reproduce

```
def reproduce(boardX, boardY, nqueens):
boardChild = [-1] * nqueens 
n = random.randint(0, (nqueens - 1)) #percentage of how much of one parent is reproduced and how much of the other parent
d = 0
for d in range(n): # the first n part of parent x
    boardChild[d] = boardX[d]

s = d + 1
for s in range(nqueens) : # the last n-(len(board)-1) part of parent y
    boardChild[s] = boardY[s]

return boardChild
```

Function Mutate

```
def mutate(child):
print('mutate')

boardMutated = [-1] * len(child)
newColumn = random.randint(0, len(child)-1)
newRow = random.randint(0, len(child)-1)
boardMutated[newColumn] = newRow

return boardMutated
```

Genetic Algorithm

```
def genetic_algorithm(board):
optimum = (len(board) - 1) * len(board) / 2
print('optimum:' + str(optimum))
nqueens = len(board)
populationSize = 20

population = []

for i in range(populationSize -1): #initializes first pooulation
    population.append([])
    for _ in range(nqueens):
        population[i].append(random.randint(0, nqueens-1))
    population[i].append(evaluate_state(population[i]))

    if evaluate_state(population[i]) == optimum:
        print("solved puzzle! 0")
        print_board(population[i])
        return 

t = 0
while t != 1000:
    population.sort(key=lambda x: x[nqueens -1 ]) #sorts the population from highest population size
    for i in range(populationSize -1):
        del population[i][-1]
    newPopulation = [ [] for _ in range(populationSize -1) ]
    newPopulation[0] = reproduce(population[1], population[0], nqueens) #
    chance = random.randint(0, 100)
    if chance < 5: # small chance that the child gets mutated
            newPopulation[0] = mutate(newPopulation[0])
            if evaluate_state(newPopulation[0]) == optimum:
                print('if evaluate_state(child) == optimum:')
                print("Solved puzzle! 1")
                print_board(newPopulation[0])
                return

    if evaluate_state(newPopulation[0]) == optimum:
        print("Solved puzzle! 2")
        print('if evaluate_state(newPopulation[1]) == optimum:')
        print_board(newPopulation[1])
        return

    l = 0

    while l != (populationSize -1):
        print(str(l))
        child = reproduce(population[l], population[l + 1], nqueens) # reproduces the new generation
        print_board(child)
        if evaluate_state(child) == optimum:
            print('if evaluate_state(child) == optimum:')
            print("Solved puzzle! 3")
            print_board(child)
            return

        chance = random.randint(0, 100)
        if chance < 5: # small chance that the child gets mutated
            child = mutate(child)
            if evaluate_state(child) == optimum:
                print('if evaluate_state(child) == optimum:')
                print("Solved puzzle! 4")
                print_board(child)
                return

        newPopulation[l] = child
        l += 1
    t += 1
```

All the print-statements were added to see which parts did execute and which did not execute. The code crashes as soon as the l reaches 18 here, which of course it should not. All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show your output error statements

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nqueens1.py", line 370, in <module>
    main()
  File "nqueens1.py", line 363, in main
    genetic_algorithm(board)
  File "nqueens1.py", line 291, in genetic_algorithm
    child = reproduce(population[l], population[l + 1], nqueens) # reproduces the new generation
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of print statements you can use python debugger, pdb. Look into it later. It can be a bit cumbersome to learn at first but soon you will begin to see its benefits. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Thanks I will look at that after I finished this assignment! @Yatin

Answer (score 1):

I think `population` only has 19 items, not 20; all the populations are initialized using `range(populationSize - 1)` which only has 19 numbers (from 0 to 18).

You can check this by also printing out `len(population)`

Comment: I think this might have been the issue. Do you see other lines where this might be a problem?

Comment: Also, the reproduce function seems to be getting rid of one of the queens? Might there be a similar issue?

Comment: You can write yourself a function to check these sorts of things, something like `check_population` and/or `check_state`, which raises an exception if something's wrong, then call it at various points to debug where exactly you're losing (or gaining) queens, losing or gaining members of the population, and generally to make sure the code is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: The other way is to break this up into multiple functions, then write tests for each separately; you'd do that on a real project, probably not on an assignment unless it's a major one.